# How to DROP data file from temp tablespace in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want drop `Temp` tablespace which have `FILE_ID` '2' and '3' because I
need the  space  in my disk. Please suggest how can I do with
steps.  Its need full . Details given below with query.

```
SQL> select FILE_ID,RELATIVE_FNO,TABLESPACE_NAME, BYTES_USED, BYTES_FREE    
 2   from V$TEMP_SPACE_HEADER;

   FILE_ID RELATIVE_FNO TABLESPACE_NAME                BYTES_USED BYTES_FREE
---------- ------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2            2 TEMP                           1073741824          0
         3            3 TEMP                           5368709120          0
         4            4 TEMP                           1.1361E+10   40894464
```

Comment: To be clear: you don't really want to drop the TEMP tablespace, you just would like to resize it by dropping some of its data files.    What impact analysis have you done?  Are you confident this action won't break your system?

Comment: APC@Thank you very  much, i want to release the size of  FILE_ID  2 and 3 , this is my local server, here need space because disk size  has been full 100%.  So i need to drop or have any other solution please provide the appropriate solution   its need full. and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please reply its need full. Thank you in advance.